# how to implement facebook login in android correctly

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to implement the facebook api to fetch data of the user when said user clicks on the facebook login button. that's it, click.. go grab the json file and return it.

the problem is that the developers guide are somewhat difficult to follow for me and the tutorials and posts and stuff i've found are very old and use deprecated code.. so i'm stuck
what i've managed to code is:

Layout:

```
   <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            fb:login_text="@string/registrarse_con_facebook" />
```

java:

```
 //global variable
 LoginButton btnRegisterFb;

 .
 .
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);


    btnRegisterFb   = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    //permissions is an array of strings with permissions needed
    btnRegisterFb.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(FacebookHelper.permissions));


}
```

i would love some guidance with this topic.

how can i display the login dialog?, how can i fetch user data?

Comment: Want it simple way? use this library: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: I created a login page for facebook using http in android...would u want that???
the project wont deal with push notifications and also it wont fetch contacts and do other stuffs that usually facebook app does..it will just login into fb and will show the fb home page..do u want that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
<string name="applicationId">ur app id </string>



<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/applicationId" />
```